# Is there a way to set the default stream in the TuneIn Radio app?

Tags: settings

I love TuneIn Radio, especially when using the 32kbps AAC audio stream.  But, every time I turn the app off and back on again it defaults to the mp3 stream.

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the default stream?

Answer (score 1):

Open the app, 
Go to Settings -> Playback. 
Check auto restart player option.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this idea: In the general settings, at the preferred stream setting, I selected the low one. In most cases this will work fine (at least in my case). This way it will choose the lower bit rate AAC stream over the higher bit rate MP3.